# gui not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I ran into the following problem with my kiosk application:

I have a window with some thumbnails. When the user clicks on a thumbnail, another window (docview) with info is displayed and in the center a document is shown..

I would like to have the docview visible instantly and then start loading the document (the document loading takes 1-3 secs)and add it to the interface afterwards.

At the moment when I click a thumb, the interfaces freezes for a second or two, and then the docview is visible with the document already..

This is what I do:

```
        viewgrid.Children.Add(docView); // the main window uses this grid to display the windows
        viewgrid.InvalidateVisual();
        viewgrid.UpdateLayout(); // at this point I would like to have the docView visible
        docView.showDocument(); //and afterwards, the loading of the document should start and be also visible eventually..
```

I tried using the LayoutUpdated event with no success..Also putting the showDocument in a separate thread didn't help either..I also read about Application.DoEvents(), but that's deprecated and seemed bad practice anyway..

How should I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a BackgroundWorker object to load the document. You said you tried threading, and it didn't work, but you need to get threading to work and I recommend you use a background worker.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

I am not sure what type of document you are loading, but I loaded a RichText file using Binding as described here:
http://www.rhyous.com/2011/08/01/loading-a-richtextbox-from-an-rtf-file-using-binding-or-a-richtextfile-control/

You would do the same thing only you load the document in a BackgroundWorker. Once the document is loaded, you update the bound property and the UI will update.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what I want..All I want to know is if there's some 'IsRendered' event, so that I know that when my layout is rendered and visible, I can start loading the document. The document itself is a powerpoint, loaded by a microsoft powerpoint interop dll..

Comment: Here is what I understood. You have an element in WPF that loads a document. You want to show the element immediately, but empty then have the document load at its own speed in a backgroundworker.

Comment: Okay, but what should I do when the backgroundworker is done with loading earlier? I can't really control the powerpoint dll..

Comment: You were right! I got it working by starting the powerpoint dll and loading the file with a backgroundworker while starting the gui, and when the loading is done, the gui is updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use async bindings. Or do it manually with another thread and Dispatcher. But it depends on that your ShowDocument is doing and that is slow.

Comment: How would I do this manually? I could have a thread waiting and when the docview screen is visible, it could start loading the document..But how do I know the screen is loaded and visible? The event layoutupdated fires up too soon..

Comment: I think i don't quite understand that your showDocument is doing. Slowly loads document from somethere and then shows it somehow?. Or it just shows some controls but their rendering is slow&

Comment: The showDocument method adds a WindowsFormHost to the docview. Then loads a document using the Microsoft Office Interop dlls, and puts this document in the windowsformhost using the SetParent call..